# Xamarin #if__ANDROID__ no inteli VS2015

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm using #if in my code like

```
var listView = new ListView();

#if __ANDROID__

//Things here are always greyed out and inteli is not working,

#endif
```

I don't understand why I don't have inteli here it always grayed out.
does someone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **#if** directive checks for Conditional compilations symbols within your project.

Open your project properties -> Build -> Conditional Compilations Symbols and add __ANDROID __ there.